# Retrieving last record of a table inside inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these three tables:

```
products
+----+--------+
| id | QRCode |
+----+--------+
|  1 | 1000   |
|  2 | 1001   |
+----+--------+

prices
+----+---------+------------+
| id | price   | product_id |
+----+---------+------------+
|  2 | $100001 |          1 |
|  3 | $100002 |          1 |
|  4 | $90001  |          2 |
|  5 | $90002  |          2 |
+----+---------+------------+

colors
+----+--------+-------------+
| id | color  | product_id  |
+----+--------+-------------+
|  1 | ffffff |           1 |
|  2 | f2f2f2 |           1 |
|  4 | aaaaaa |           2 |
|  5 | a3a3a3 |           2 |
+----+--------+-------------+
```

I would like to merge these three in a way that returns:

- group_concat colors based on product_id
- retrieves **last record of each grouped price**

This is the desired output:

```
+--------+----------------+-------------+-------------+
| QRCode |    colors      |    price    | product_id  |
+--------+----------------+-------------+-------------+
|  1000  | ffffff, f2f2f2 |   $100002   |      1      |
|  1001  | aaaaaa, a3a3a3 |   $90002    |      2      |
+--------+----------------+-------------+-------------+
```

**Things I tried:**

The query below returns product_id of last record of each grouped price

```
SELECT product_id FROM price where id IN 
                                        (SELECT max(id) FROM price
                                         GROUP BY product_id)
```

Then I tried to put query above in this query as a subquery

```
SELECT products.QRCode, priceSubQ.price, GROUP_CONCAT(colors.color) as colors FROM products
INNER JOIN colors on colors.product_id = products.id
INNER JOIN ( /* I put query above here */ ) as priceSubQ ON priceSubQ.product_id = products.id
GROUP BY products.id
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `ORDER BY` in conjunction with `DESCEND` and then `LIMIT`

Comment: Tip: Don't store '$'

Comment: @ansi_lumen could you explain it in more detail?

Comment: @Strawberry I Don't, thought it would help better understand my question

Comment: @Sajad It doesn't. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should work (not tested)..

```
SELECT 
    products.QRCode, 
    priceSubQ.price, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(colors.color) as colors 
FROM 
    products
    LEFT JOIN colors 
        ON colors.product_id = products.id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            MAX(p1.id) as p1maxId,
            p2.price AS price,
            p2.product_id AS product_id
        FROM
            prices p1
            INNER JOIN prices p2
                ON p1.p1maxId = p2.id
        GROUP BY
            p1.product_id
    ) AS priceSubQ 
        ON priceSubQ.product_id = products.id
GROUP BY 
    products.id
```

Comment: @J A I tested it... didn't work, couldn't retrieve last row of price table, found my answer, thanks anyway

Comment: @Sajad: Glad you found your solution. Why not post the solution it here so that others can benefit from it? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I came across this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) which helped me understand the problem

Changed inner query to:

```
SELECT product_id FROM ANY_VALUE(price) where id IN 
                                    (SELECT max(id) FROM price
                                     GROUP BY product_id) group by product_id
```

solved my problem.